# PCI raidcard not detected on Kernel above version 4.10.9

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, pci

Unfortunately, my raidcard is no longer recognized on a kernel version higher than 4.10.9. So on 4.10.9 it is showing my disks, but after updating to 4.11 it is not working anymore.

This is some Systeminfo from `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:    Kernel: 4.14.295 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Console: tty 0 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: X470 GAMING PLUS MAX (MS-7B79) v: 3.0 serial: <filter>
           UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: H.D2 date: 09/26/2021
CPU:       Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 L2 cache: 3 MiB
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 88797
           Speed: 3600 MHz min/max: 2200/3700 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3600 2: 2878 3: 2869 4: 3593 5: 3594
           6: 2879 7: 2880 8: 3594 9: 3598 10: 2874 11: 3593 12: 2873
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 730] vendor: ZOTAC driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 27:00.0
           Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 270x69
           Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console for root.
Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio vendor: ZOTAC driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 27:00.1
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel
           v: kernel bus ID: 2a:00.4
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.14.295
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI
           port: d000 bus ID: 22:00.0
           IF: enp34s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Device-2: Intel 82572EI Gigabit Ethernet driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: c000 bus ID: 25:00.0
           IF: enp37s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 232.89 GiB used: 39.07 GiB (16.8%)
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Crucial model: CT250MX500SSD4 size: 232.89 GiB temp: 33 C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 226.74 GiB used: 39.07 GiB (17.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 3.4 MiB (0.7%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 977 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/sda3
Sensors:   Message: No sensors data was found. Is sensors configured?
Info:      Processes: 174 Uptime: 10m Memory: 31.4 GiB used: 624.8 MiB (1.9%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.1
           Packages: 519 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 inxi: 3.3.01
```

`dmesg` on Kernel 4.9.330 (working):

```
[    1.099063] pci 0000:00:03.2: scanning [bus 28-28] behind bridge, pass 0
[    1.099099] pci_bus 0000:28: scanning bus
[    1.099112] pci 0000:28:00.0: [1000:0060] type 00 class 0x010400
[    1.099136] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc940000-0xfc97ffff 64bit]
[    1.099147] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xe000-0xe0ff]
[    1.099164] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc93ffff 64bit]
[    1.099185] pci 0000:28:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfc980000-0xfc99ffff pref]
[    1.099251] pci 0000:28:00.0: supports D1
[    1.111045] pci_bus 0000:28: fixups for bus
[    1.111045] pci 0000:00:03.2: PCI bridge to [bus 28]
[    1.111049] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    1.111051] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc9fffff]
[    1.111055] pci_bus 0000:28: bus scan returning with max=28
[    1.111058] pci 0000:00:07.1: scanning [bus 29-29] behind bridge, pass 0
```

`lspci -v` on Kernel 4.9.330:

```
28:00.0 RAID bus controller: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 234, IOMMU group 16
    Memory at fc940000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at fc900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at fc980000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [b0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c4] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d4] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [ec] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas
    Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
```

`dmesg` on Kernel 4.14.295 (not working):

```
[    0.312039] pci 0000:00:03.2: scanning [bus 28-28] behind bridge, pass 0
[    0.512001] pci_bus 0000:28: scanning bus
[    0.712001] pci_bus 0000:28: fixups for bus
[    0.712001] pci 0000:00:03.2: PCI bridge to [bus 28]
[    0.712005] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.712007] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc9fffff]
[    0.712011] pci_bus 0000:28: bus scan returning with max=28
[    0.712013] pci 0000:00:07.1: scanning [bus 29-29] behind bridge, pass 0
```

Both comments (`lspci -s 28:00.0` and `lspci -n -s 28:0.0`) return nothing on Kernel 4.14.295.
And `modprobe megaraid_sas` doesnt change anything.

Unfortunately, I'm a newbie in the area of kernel compiling (I used this tutorial https://askubuntu.com/a/513243) and don't know exactly what modifications I should make to debug better. I've already compiled the kernel and enabled PCI debugging.
For the Kernel 4.9.330 I used this configfile https://www.pastery.net/uuccaz/
and for 4.14.295 I used https://www.pastery.net/adfuyx/.

I also looked for changes in the change logs https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.10.9 and https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.11.1, but unfortunately I didn't find anything there either.

I am very grateful for every idea!

Comment: are you booting your machine in legacy bios mode or in uefi mode?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Im booting in UEFI-mode.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Ive added device pci and device mfi to my .config and compiled the kernel... unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader still no changes in `lsblk` and `lspci`.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Note that https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/freebsd-manpages/mfi.4freebsd.en.html refers to Debian with a FreeBSD kernel, not to Debian with Linux kernel. The FreeBSD kernel uses different drivers from the Linux one, and so the man page would not be applicable to Linux.

Comment: What does `lspci -s 28:00.0` and `lspci -n -s 28:0.0` show (on the 4.14.295 kernel)? (note: add this info to your question, not in a comment). Did you compile the kernel yourself? or install a kernel package for whatever distro you're using? Speaking of which, is this a PC or some kind of appliance like a NAS?   Please edit your question and add details about your system's hardware and distro.  Did you try running `modprobe megaraid_sas`? Was the megaraid_sas module actually compiled for your 4.14 kernel? BTW, the LSI 1078 is ancient (only PCI-e 1.0 and SATA 2) but should still be supported.

Comment: @telcoM you are right. the right module for the linux kernel is megaraid_sas .

Comment: @cas Thank you for the further debugging steps. Ive added the information in the question.

Comment: have you tried to boot your machine with an ubuntu live perhaps the last one? just curious to know if your car will be recognized.

Comment: i'm seeing you are using debian bullseye, what's happen with the official kernel ? is the card still missing at boot?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I think it really has to do directly with the Linux kernel and PCI. Unfortunately, the card also does not work with Ubuntu and the standard Debian kernel.